# How do I clear Polymer paper-input?

Tags: polymer

I've been toying with Polymer, and a simple app that takes input from a paper-input element, and put it in a list.

I just updated with bower update, and now I can't seem to clear the input field.

This is my code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="input-reason">
    <template>
        <content select="paper-input" on-change="{{valueChanged}}"></content>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('input-reason', {
        valueChanged: function() {
            var inputText = this.getElementsByTagName('paper-input')[0].value;
            console.log(inputText);
            this.getElementsByTagName('paper-input')[0].value = "";
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This worked before I updated, now nothing happens.
I'm guessing something changed in either paper-input or core-input, but I don't really have an idea what it could be.

Another thing, I'm wondering if it's really necessary to jump through hoops like that to get and set the value of paper-input. It looks so crude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use inputValue and commit to notify the changes:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="input-reason">
    <template>
    <content select="paper-input" inputValue="{{ value }}" on-change="{{ valueChanged }}"></content>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('input-reason', {
            valueChanged: function () {
                var input = this.getElementsByTagName('paper-input')[0];
                var inputText = input.inputValue;
                console.log(inputText);
                input.inputValue = 'sd';
                input.commit();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see that the description has been updated. I will try inputValue.